# Django model query's database access mechanism

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

```
class parent(models.Model):
    ap=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(("ap","user"),)
        db_table='parent'


class child(models.Model):
    userkey=models.ForeignKey(parent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column="ap")
    pn=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    st=models.CharField(max_length=10,default='Y')

    def get_ap(self):
        return self.ap.ap
    def get_pn(self):
        return self.pn
    class Meta:
        db_table="child"
        unique_together=(('userkey','pn'),)
```

Let's say i have ap="apkey" then i can access all child model object for "apkey" by following query.

```
child_obj=child.objects.filter(userkey__ap="apkey")
```

This can be also done without using foreign key relation as follows.

```
parent_obj=parent.objects.get(ap="apkey")
child_obj=child.objects.filter(userkey=parent_obj)
```

What i have to know is that how many database access is occurred while executing query in both methods. ?

In the second, we knows that it access parent table once and then access child table once. Hence actually two sql query occurs.

What about the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django querysets are lazy in nature. [see here in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).
So technically **only one** database hit occurs when you execute the second piece of code.

Elaborating further, 
stating from the docs.

```
q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
q = q.exclude(body_text__icontains="food")
print(q)
```

**Though this looks like three database hits, in fact it hits the database only once, at the last line (print(q)). In general, the results of a QuerySet aren’t fetched from the database until you “ask” for them.**

For backward relations [see docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible), upon running the settings.py, backward relations are created and they too should take only one hit technically. But I'm not absolutely sure about this since I didn't find anything about this in the docs that I remember as of now.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking into that

Answer (score 1):

As @shivam said the queryset are lazy in nature and they are evaluated only when you ask for them. If you want to see what are the sql queries that are being executed you can use the `connection`. But you can see only the queries of the current processes. The best way to see what queries are being executed is to use some tool like [django-debug-tool](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar).

```
from django.db import connection
parent_obj=parent.objects.get(ap="apkey")
child_obj=child.objects.filter(userkey=parent_obj)
print(len(connection.queries))
```

To view a query you can use [`query` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) of a queryset. It contains the query that is to be executed.
e.g.:

`Mymodels.objects.all().query`

Comment: len(connection.queries) actually prints the total number of queries used till now. isn't it?

Comment: Also they are represent the actual mysql queries, are they?

Comment: Yes it prints the total number of queries used till now. And `connection.queries` prints a list of sql queries that are used by the processes so far.

Comment: This may helps. After making it sure, i will reply you.

Comment: I will also try out the debug tool. thereafter i will reply

Comment: Can we also use following to view the query. "print object.query"

Comment: Yeah. but when i tried to view the parent_obj it shows "object has no attribute query". Why?, are they hit the database?

Comment: @vishnumc the `parent_obj` is an object not a `queryset`.

Comment: oh. So when we use get, it will not access the database right?. But when we use that object it will hit. Similarly but filter will hit the database while creating the objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149107/discussion-between-sasuke-and-vishnu-m-c).